# Rest Easy, How to accept XML / JSON requests as Source document object in post method

Tags: xml, json, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

What I am trying to do is, if client is sending JSON or XML in post, it should be rendered as Source document parameter?

```
@POST
Response doPost(Source source){
}
```

Any Idea. I tried looking at `MessageBodyReader/Writer` some Interception methods but nothing seems to be working, and I believe `MessageBodyReader` are not longer supported in 3.0.10 Resteasy.

Answer (score 0):

XML is supported by default by a JAXB provider. This means you need a JAXB annotation for the `Source` class, and follow whatever other rules that apply to JAXB annotations/mappings

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Source {
    ....
}
```

> "I believe MessageBodyReader are not longer supported in 3.0.10 Resteasy."

Actually this is a JAX-RS class/interface/provider that must be supported, and *is*.  Normally a Jackson provider is used, which  `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`.

If you are using Maven, you can simply add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and the provider should be automatically register.

If you're not using Maven, get all these jars

[image]

They should all be included in the [Resteasy distribution](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) (though the link doesn't show a 3.0.10 download - not sure where to get it)

---

### UPDATE

So with further clarification from the OP, the requirement is to be able to use [`javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html).

You could write a custom `MessageBodyReader`, and create the `StreamSource` there and return it. For example

**`MessageBodyReader`**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

@Provider
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class StreamSourceMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<StreamSource> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type t, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        return type.isAssignableFrom(StreamSource.class);
    }

    @Override
    public StreamSource readFrom(Class<StreamSource> type, Type type1, 
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap<String, String> mm, 
            InputStream in) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        return new StreamSource(reader);
    }   
}
```

**Resource**

```
@Path("source")
public class SourceResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response postSource(StreamSource source) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Response=");
        try (BufferedReader reader = (BufferedReader) source.getReader()) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        return Response.ok(builder.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

**App Config**

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(SimpleResource.class);
        classes.add(SourceResource.class);
        return classes;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
        singletons.add(new StreamSourceMessageBodyReader());
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

**Test**

> `$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
>                 -d '{"hello":"world"}' http://localhost:8080/api/source`
>   **Result:**
>   `Response={"hello":"world"}`

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet, but it was not that easy thing i asked. if it was it was just I wanted a custom JAXB object, I would not have asked this question. I hope you know Source is a JavaX SourceStream document object here.

Comment: Basically what I want is, I want to intercept the Request before it is being processed by post method in a resource & based on media type, I want to convert data in json or xml format to a StreamSource object, which then should be passed as variable to post method.

Comment: You should have mentioned that. You could either write a custom `MessagBodyReader`, or simply accept an `InputStream` and in the method, create a `StreamSource` from the `InputStream`. If you want to write a `MessageBodyReader` it would be as simple as wrapping the `InputStream` parameter in the `StreamSource` and returning it